# Why $f$ is a continuous map?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $E$ a finite dimensional complex Hilbert space. Let $T\in \mathcal{L}(E)$, where  $\mathcal{L}(E)$ the algebra
 of all bounded linear operators from $E$ to $E$.

We consider the following map $f: S^1 \to \mathbb{C}: x \mapsto \langle Tx\; |\;x\rangle$, where $S^1:=\{x\in E\,;\;\|x\|=1\}$.

Why $f$ is continuous?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to prove this? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I think it is the restriction of the map from $E$ to $E$ which is continuous because it is linear in finite dimensional

Comment: @Thierry It's continuous, but it isn't linear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(x_n)$ be a convegent sequence in $S^1$ with limit $x \in S^1$.

Since $T$ is bounded, we have $Tx_n \to Tx$. The inner product is continuous, hence  $\langle Tx_n\; |\;x_n\rangle \to  \langle Tx\; |\;x\rangle$.

This gives $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.